Django cache requests and only allow refresh daily
So I have this Admin dashboard for an e-commerce website where there are all kinds of statistics about sales and customers. Now this data is hosted in AWS RDS and the dashboard is made with django templates. So logically whenever the admin goes to this page it gets refreshed and it queries the AWS RDS. Now this data does not change in real-time the dashboard data gets updated daily in the database (this is done with dbt so this has nothing to do with django) so it doesnt make sense to run these queries multiple times a day because the data will not change on the dashboard.
So what I need is something to cache the data once the admin goes to this dashboard and then invalidate the cache at say midnight. Anyone has done something like this or has any advice on how to create something like this? Thanks in advance for all replies!

In your view (or middleware) you can calculate how long the page should be valid (data_change_time - current_time) and then set the max-age using patch_cache_control. Each individual client will still trigger a database query, though, so if you really want to avoid that you can use Django's internal caching system (see the rest of the documentation on that page).
